# reading PHP Session ID in console

Tags: javascript, session-cookies, php

I am trying to read all the cookie values by the code

```
cookie = document.cookie
```

And when I do alert(cookie) or console.log(cookie) I get the following data

```
phpcsls=4; __utma=229677836.804108415.1388064796.1388064796.1388064796.1; __utmb=229677836.5.10.1388064796; __utmc=229677836; __utmz=229677836.1388064796.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

But if I open the developer console and check the cookies folder this is what I have
[image]

And I am interested in reading the PHPSESSID from the cookie. How should I do that ?

Comment: Why do you need to have the session id in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at your developer console, you can see that your session cookie is set as `HTTP`.

It means that the session cookie is **HttpOnly**. Take a look at [setcookie() documentation](http://php.net/setcookie) and you will see that:

> When TRUE the cookie will be made accessible only through the HTTP protocol. This means that the cookie won't be accessible by scripting languages, such as JavaScript. It has been suggested that this setting can effectively help to reduce identity theft through XSS attacks (although it is not supported by all browsers), but that claim is often disputed. Added in PHP 5.2.0. TRUE or FALSE

Since the session cookie is HttpOnly, it is impossible to read it from Javascript. So the short answer is: it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the http collumn, you see a checkmark. This means that cookie is [httpOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) and can't be read from within javascript.

This is a security measure to prevent sensitive cookies being stolen through javascript exploits.